# How can I pass a parameter to the future property function in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the argument of a route to my function which is inside the FutureBuilder.

Please see my code below.

```
class StudyDetailsArguments {
  final String listid;

  StudyDetailsArguments(this.listid);
}

// A widget that extracts the necessary arguments from the ModalRoute.
class ExtractStudyDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/studydetails';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder(

  // Here I want to pass in the args.listid but I cant figure out how to get it in there
    future: getDetails("cc0e5c1f-02b0-4f4f-9f51-fa70ac7e9c08"),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     // here is fine to use the argument
      final StudyDetailsArguments  args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Build the widget with data.
        //return Text('hasData: ${snapshot.data}');
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(snapshot.data),
      ),
            body:
            Center(
            child:
            Text('${snapshot.data}'))
              );
            } else {
              // We can show the loading view until the data comes back.
            return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Loading..."),
            ),
            body:
            Center(
                child:
                Text('Loading...'))
        );
      }
    },
  );
}

Future<String> getDetails(listid) async {
  var details = "";
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection('list')
      .document(listid)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
        print(ds.data["title"]);
        // use ds as a snapshot
        details = ds.data["title"];
    return ds.data;
  });
  return details;
}
```

I want to use this line args.listid instead of cc0e5c1f-02b0-4f4f-9f51-fa70ac7e9c08 but I can't seem to figure out the way to pass the parameter. How I send the parameter value (which now is not used) to the widget is this way in a widget:

```
 onTap: () => {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ExtractStudyDetails.routeName,
                        arguments: StudyDetailsArguments(
                          study.listid,
                        ))
                  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  final StudyDetailsArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

  return FutureBuilder(
    future: getDetails(args.listid),
    [...]
  )
}
```

Read more on [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still new to dart and flutter, this was simpler than I thought!

Comment: i want to add that it initializing a future value in build method might not work as you might expect, it is better to initialize it inside `initState()` of a `StatefulWidget` -> `State` then pass the instance of future to `FutureBuilder` so that future is not initialized every build call, which can be many.
As such i would suggest using StatefulWidget.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will try this also if that's the preferred way.